# Efficiently check if array has duplicates

Tags: c, algorithm

There is an array of 1000 elements, all the elements are Normally distributed within a range of 1 - 10000000. How can I check for duplicates faster than `O(n^2)`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The numbers cannot be Normally distributed unless there are duplicates.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do it better than with a complexity of O(n^2).

Comment: A simple sort/traverse will give `O(n log n)`

Comment: @alex1988 Please understand how to ask here. This question cannot be answered because it appears to be your homework, you just dump it here directly. Most SO users will be voting to close this "*question*". Because it's not a question.

Comment: @alex1988 just like Eugene said, sort it then traverse it and you can check the current index with the next index.

Comment: @ schil227 , my code works but it's just a loop within a loop. I was wondering if there is a better solution with better time complexity

Comment: @iharob, I'm sorry, it isn't a homework question but i get it

Comment: @user3386109 Well, a normally distributing random function can be used to generate this array, and there is a non-zero probability that there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: Obviously you can do better than n^2, since you can sort it in better than n^2.

Comment: @ David Schwartz @ Omid CompSCI @ Eugene Sh thanks, I also thought about sorting but i wanted to see if i'm missing a better solution regarding the fact that the array is  Normally distributed. i thought it was mantion because it was important for the solution

Comment: You might be able to utilize the fact of the distribution to get a better *average* time complexity. Just to give you the idea: You know that the numbers in the middle of the range are most likely to occur. So you can start looking for these numbers only in `O(n)` time. If you are not lucky, the worst case complexity will be `O(n^2)`. But in average I believe it would be `O(n)`.

Comment: There are solutions with O(n) time complexity, but they have a larger constant factor than sorting. Since `log₂1000 = 10`, an O(n) solution with a large constant factor won't be faster than sorting when `n=1000`.

Comment: @user3386109 Or as proposed in the answer - a large space complexity.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Note that 10000000 is more than `n²` when `n` is 1000, so just scanning that array for values greater than 1 is worse than `n²`

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, but it's space, not time. But of course it is not scalable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's also time, as you need to iterate over the additional array, which takes `O(max_num)` time.

Comment: @HonzaDejdar There is no need to iterate. Once you update some index, you can check it and return the result right away if it was set before.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Right! I am updatimg the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in `O(max_num + n)` time complexity and in `O(max_num)` space complexity, where `max_num` is maximum number you can have in your array,  using additional array.

You allocate new array `countsArr` of size 10000001 and initialize all of it's elements to `0`. Then you iterate over your primary array, and in every iteration, you add `1` to the new array's element on the index of the number you are currently processing. For example, on first position of your primary array is number `15`, so you add `1` to `arr[15]`, etc. After you are done with the iteration, you just iterate over `countsArr`, and if you find an element, which value is greater than `1`, then there are duplicities in your array, otherwise there are not.

EDIT: This is generally faster solution than `O(n^2)` for large n, but since you have 1000 elements, `1,000^2 = 1,000,000`, `O(n^2)` will be actually faster for `n = 1,000` than the solution I proposed.

EDIT2: As Eugene Sh. pointed out, there is actually no need to iterate over the aditional array, as you can immediatelly say, that the array has duplicities, when you increment an index, which already holds 1. When you do, you can say that there is at least one duplicity and terminate. This improvement makes the algorithm have `O(n)` time complexity in the worst case (no duplicities).

Answer (score 0):

use hashmap to do it if you donot care about the space. The time complexity is O(n). n is the size of the lists

Comment: STL map is c++ feature and implementing his own hashmap seems like a overkill to me.

Comment: the method you are using is kind of the bucket sort. Since the problem is the maximum could be a little bit large while the size of the list is small. I do not think it is an efficient way to do it.